# Library not loaded: @rpath/libpython3.5m.dylib --> Jupyter Notebook Kernel does not start

Tags: anaconda, jupyter-notebook, dylib

I tried to update the notebook version from the Anaconda Navigator and got an error. After that the notebook starts, but the kernel does not. I uninstalled anaconda with anaconda clean and installed again, but the error persists. The message it prints on the terminal is:

```
[I 17:03:55.689 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (4/5), new random ports
kernel eaf804ca-e585-4dfa-b30c-09cd1de604eb restarted
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libpython3.5m.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/phribeiro/anaconda/bin/python3
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Users/phribeiro/anaconda/bin/../lib/libpython3.5m.dylib: file too short
[W 17:03:58.699 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restart failed
[W 17:03:58.700 NotebookApp] Kernel eaf804ca-e585-4dfa-b30c-09cd1de604eb died, removing from map.
kernel eaf804ca-e585-4dfa-b30c-09cd1de604eb restarted failed!
[W 17:03:58.718 NotebookApp] 410 DELETE /api/sessions/865314d0-bcc2-42e1-ae17-98c82511ebef (::1): Kernel deleted before session
[W 17:03:58.718 NotebookApp] Kernel deleted before session
[W 17:03:58.719 NotebookApp] 410 DELETE /api/sessions/865314d0-bcc2-42e1-ae17-98c82511ebef (::1) 4.14ms referer=http://localhost:8889/notebooks/Untitled11.ipynb
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you show the commands you ran to help us answer your question?
Also, when you quote code or error messages, use the site's code formatting functionality: select the log text or code with your mouse and then click on the {} button. It will be much easier for others to read and understand.

Comment: Joanis, thanks - newbie here!  I just tried to start the with the $ jupyter notebook command. The notebook starts, but as soon as I open a notebook or create a new one, this error message appears on the terminal. I installed a fresh version from anaconda and the error persists. Python 3.7 version.

Comment: This is much easier to read, thanks! You might also want to specify what OS you're using to get help from the right people.

Comment: MacOs Sierra V10.12.6

Comment: I did the following and it worked, don't really know why:  

Open command prompt
conda install ipykernel
conda create -n Python3.6Test python=3.6
conda activate Python3.6Test
pip install ipykernel
python -m ipykernel install --name Python3.6Test